# Migrations of Keycloak from v16 to v21 doesn't import realms and users

Tags: postgresql, docker, keycloak

We have dockerized Keycloak v16 and now we would like to migrate to a version v21.

We uses Postgres database and we have inside this database already created realms and users.

When we upgraded to a v21 everything works except that Keycloak shows that realms are empty and users as well.

If I inspect database, all users and realms are still there...

How to tell Keycloak to read old realms and users?

New docker file

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.0.2

COPY themes/ /opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/
ADD ./standalone-ha.xml /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone-ha.xm
```

standalone-ha.xml

```
<spi name="connectionsJpa">
                <provider name="default" enabled="true">
                    <properties>
                        <property name="dataSource" value="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS"/>
                        <property name="initializeEmpty" value="true"/>
                        <property name="migrationStrategy" value="update"/>
                        <property name="migrationExport" value="${jboss.home.dir}/keycloak-database-update.sql"/>
                        <property name="schema" value="${env.DB_SCHEMA:public}"/>
                    </properties>
                </provider>
            </spi>
```

docker-compose file

```
  keycloak:
    image: mykeycloak
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR: xxxx
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: postgres
      DB_SCHEMA: public
      DB_PASSWORD: xxxx
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: xxxx
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: xxxx
      KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL: http://localhost:8080/auth/
    volumes:
      - ./common/keycloak/disable-theme-cache.cli:/opt/jboss/startup-scripts/disable-theme-cache.cli
    command: start-dev --http-relative-path /auth --spi-connections-jpa-legacy-migration-strategy=update
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

### EDIT:

I figure out that Keycloak is not connecting to a database. I always insert the same realms so I though that new and old are in same database.

So the question is how to connect correctly to a Postgres container.

I change the docker-compose file to a

```
  db:
    image: postgres:13.2
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'xxx'
    # volumes:
    # - /Volumes/DATA/docker_volume/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data




  keycloak:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: mykeycloak
    environment:
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_ADDR: db
      KC_DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      KC_DB_USER: postgres
      KC_DB_SCHEMA: public
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: xxx
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: keycloak_admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: xxx
      KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL: http://localhost:8080/auth/
    volumes:
      - ./common/keycloak/disable-theme-cache.cli:/opt/jboss/startup-scripts/disable-theme-cache.cli
    command: start-dev --http-relative-path /auth
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

now I get the error

```
2023-06-22 10:18:30 2023-06-22 08:18:30,593 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator] (JPA Startup Thread: keycloak-default) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
2023-06-22 10:18:30     at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:319)
2023-06-22 10:18:30     at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
2023-06-22 10:18:30     at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:247)
2023-06-22 10:18:30     at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:434)
2023-06-22 10:18:30     at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:291)
2023-06-22 10:18:30     at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)
2023-06-22 10:18:30     at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229)
2023-06-22 10:18:30     at org.postgresql.ds.common.BaseDataSource.getConnection(BaseDataSource.java:103)
2023-06-22 10:18:30     at org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource.getXAConnection(PGXADataSource.java:49)
2023-06-22 10:18:30     at org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource.getXAConnection(PGXADataSource.java:35)
2023-06-22 10:18:30     at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:232)
2023-06-22 10:18:30     at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:536)
2023-06-22 10:18:30     at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:517)
2023-06-22 10:18:30     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
2023-06-22 10:18:30     at io.agroal.pool.util.PriorityScheduledExecutor.beforeExecute(PriorityScheduledExecutor.java:75)
2023-06-22 10:18:30     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
2023-06-22 10:18:30     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
2023-06-22 10:18:30     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
2023-06-22 10:18:30 Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2023-06-22 10:18:30     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
2023-06-22 10:18:30     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
2023-06-22 10:18:30     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542)
2023-06-22 10:18:30     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597)
2023-06-22 10:18:30     at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
2023-06-22 10:18:30     at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
2023-06-22 10:18:30     at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:241)
2023-06-22 10:18:30     at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98)
2023-06-22 10:18:30     at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:109)
2023-06-22 10:18:30     at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235)
2023-06-22 10:18:30     ... 17 more
2023-06-22 10:18:30
```

Comment: You must use the environment variables KC_DB_ ...
     - KC_DB_VENDOR=postgres
      - KC_DB_ADDR=postgres
      - KC_DB_DATABASE=keycloak
      - KC_DB_USER=keycloak
      - KC_DB_PASSWORD=....

and the standalone-ha.xml isn't used at all, since kc is now based on quarkus. Use a keycloak.conf file instead.

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't change anything. Might be, that my questions is misleading. (I will change it a bit). The Keycloak successfully connect to database. In the same database create new realm. But read only one realm. If I inspect database, I can see all realms but only once created with new version are read.

Comment: Sorry... I was mistaken.. it actualy don't connect to a database... I try to add random realm and it didn't show in db

Comment: How do you start your docker-instance? You can  pass the db as parameters for example: (docker-compose.yml) keycloak2:
    image: docker-repo.mid.de:5000/mid-keycloak_feature-kc21:latest
    command: start-dev --log-level WARN --db postgres --db-url-database keycloak21 --http-relative-path /auth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## For anyone still having this problem:

I discovered that this docker image silently failed to connect to an external Postgres database.

Because there was no error I assumed that the connection was established but I was wrong.

#### In the new version, new environment parameters was added

The correct parameters for connecting the postgres database to a Keycloak docker image are:

```
  keycloak:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.0.2
    environment:
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_ADDR: db
      KC_DB_URL_DATABASE: keycloak
      KC_DB_URL_HOST: db
      KC_DB_URL_PORT: 5432
      KC_DB_SCHEMA: public
      KC_DB_USERNAME: XXX
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: XXX
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: XXX
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: XXX
      KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL: http://localhost:8080/auth/
    volumes:
      - ./common/keycloak/disable-theme-cache.cli:/opt/jboss/startup-scripts/disable-theme-cache.cli
    command: start-dev --http-relative-path /auth
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```